# Is it possible to have MEF instantiate a class multiple times?

Tags: c#, mef

So let's say I have an interface `IMultiplayerService` and several classes implementing it, such as a `Pbw3` class. Now `Pbw3` represents a particular server app, but there could be multiple instances of that server - one that I run, one that a friend runs, etc.

Is there any way to have MEF instantiate `Pbw3` multiple times? Or is it limited to one instance of each imported class?

I was thinking one workaround might be to create a factory class for each multiplayer server class, and have MEF create those instead, but I was hoping there's an easier way...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MEF's [ExportFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.exportfactory-1?view=netframework-4.8).

You can import `ExportFactory<IMultiplayerService>` and then create new instances as required:

```
[Import]
public ExportFactory<IMultiplayerService> MultiplayerServiceFactory { get; set; }
```

```
var instance1 = MultiplayerServiceFactory.CreateExport().Value
var instance2 = MultiplayerServiceFactory.CreateExport().Value
```